# How do I know whether to accept APT repository changes?

Tags: apt

When I run `sudo apt update` (on a DigitalOcean Ubuntu server), I get this message:

```
E: Repository 'https://packages.redis.io/deb jammy InRelease' changed its 'Origin' value from '' to 'packages.redis.io'
N: Repository 'https://packages.redis.io/deb jammy InRelease' changed its 'Suite' value from '' to 'jammy'
N: This must be accepted explicitly before updates for this repository can be applied. See apt-secure(8) manpage for details.
Do you want to accept these changes and continue updating from this repository? [y/N]
```

I know how to accept the changes (just enter 'y'). What I don't understand is how, in a situation like this, I know whether to accept them or not.

Comment: accept it if you know the repository. if you don't, remove it from the sources.list.d, it seems to me that the repository had no version enabled and has changed this